# Relation between feedback delay and oscillation of op-amp

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, oscillator, oscillation

This is from TI Precision Labs - Op Amps: Stability - Introduction presentation [here](https://training.ti.com/ti-precision-labs-op-amps-stability-introduction). He is trying to explain how delay can cause oscillation intuitively from time domain.

This is an excerpt from the presentation:

> Too much delay between the amplifier output in the inverting feedback
> node is a straightforward way to visualize the root cause of op amp
> stability issues. The effects of feedback delay are displayed in this
> example by observing the voltages at the amplifier output, Vopa, and
> the amplifier inverting input, Vfb, when a step is applied to the
> input, Vin. When Vin changes, Vopa responds in an effort to set Vfb
> equal to Vin to reestablish the virtual short between the inputs.
>
> **However, the feedback delay results in an erroneous voltage at Vopa by
> the time Vfb equals Vin at 0 volts**. As a result, Vfb continues to rise
> and overshoots the input voltage, causing Vopa to reverse directions.
> Depending on the severity of the delay, the output may settle, or may
> result in a sustained oscillation as shown here.

Can anyone explain the bold part? How the feedback delay causes erroneous voltage at `Vopa` at that time?
What is `Vopa` supposed to be if the circuit is working correctly?
In this circuit, how can you draw the waveform of `Vopa` or `Vfb`?
Because they're inter-related it's hard to make a drawing for oscillation cases like that.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110981/discussion-on-question-by-anhnha-relation-between-feedback-delay-and-oscillation).

Comment: A 741 is unusable open loop in linear mode due to high gain 1e6 and 3Hz LPF integrating Miller Compensation.  But somehow I tweaked this 741 with 271uV of offset with a 1uV slider to null the offset open loop. You can see the 100Hz integration effect and tweak the offset slider. Try to null it.  All the rules apply  in time and frequency domain in linear mode except no thermal + noise effects here.  http://tinyurl.com/y44lef3j

Comment: I found this article from TI.
I think this will help to understand.
Thankyou.
https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/posts/why-op-amps-oscillate-an-intuitive-look-at-two-frequent-causes